# Why isn't this regular expression returning anything?

Tags: php, regex

```
preg_match_all('/<p>.*:</p>/gm', $content, $matches);
var_dump($matches); //ouput is NULL
```

I want something like this: `<p>The Ideal Candidate:</p>` to match but not `<p>Some more text</p>`. The requirement being it must contain a `<p>` tag followed by some text and at the end it must contain a `:` followd by the end of the p tag (`</p>` ).

Note: I tried escaping the ending p tag, but it is still not working. 
Updated code:

```
preg_match_all('/<p>.*:<\/p>/gm', "<p>The Ideal Candidate:</p>", $matches);
```

Comment: It's probably resulting in an error, because the actual expression is `/<p>.*:</` and `p` or `>` are not valid modifiers. You have to escape the inner ``\`` or use different modifiers.

Comment: Hint: How many slashes does it contain?

Comment: *cough* Don't parse HTML with regex *cough*

Comment: @Rocket: why not? And what do you think I should do instead? I'm open to suggestions...

Comment: You can use an HTML parser... and in your updated code, you did not escape the ``\``. Make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to see all error messages. Then you don't have to guess around anymore.

Comment: I did escape the \, but it did not show up on here

Comment: @AllisonC: using the back-tick character (same key as the tilde) instead of `<code>` blocks is much easier to read in the source, easier in my opinion to write initially, and does not require you to escape characters that might otherwise require HTML entities (see my edits) - also doesn't cause problems with the `\ ` escape character :D

Comment: Thanks.. I will try that in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the `/` or use another delimiter

```
 /<p>(.*?:)<\/p>/m
```

or

```
 #<p>(.*?:)</p>#m
```

Tested:

```
preg_match_all('#<p>(.*?:)</p>#m', "<p>The Ideal Candidate:</p>", $m);
print_r($m)
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <p>The Ideal Candidate:</p>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => The Ideal Candidate:
        )

)
```

Comment: @AllisonC: There're no `g` modifier.

Answer (score 2):

`g`is not a valid modifier, see [PHP: Pattern modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). You should pay close attention to the warnings PHP issue. When running

```
preg_match_all("/<p>.*:<\/p>/gm", "<p>The Ideal Candidate:</p>", $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

I get

> Warning: `preg_match_all()`: Unknown modifier '`g`' in Command line code on line 1

Whereas the same line without the `g`modifier yields

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <p>The Ideal Candidate:</p>
        )
)
```